# DNS Error: Loading from master file failed:

Tags: apache, dns

I'm not very skilled at debugging DNS issues. I'm trying to configure two named virtual hosts in apache2 at foo.com and dev.foo.com

Currently I'm getting a DNS error that I'm not sure how to resolve, and whether it's related to my apache configuration. However, apache does not complain or submit an error log on reload.

```
dns_master_load: /dev/shm/bind/DO/db.foo.com:14: www.foo.com: CNAME and other data
zone foo.com/IN: loading from master file /dev/shm/bind/DO/db.foo.com failed: CNAME and other data
zone foo.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

My zone file is the following:

```
$TTL    1800
@       IN  SOA NS1.nsexample.COM.  hostmaster.foo.com. (
            1378763038 ; last update: 2013-09-09 21:43:58 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
             IN      NS      NS1.nsexample.COM.
                     NS      NS2.nsexample.COM.
                     NS      NS3.nsexample.COM.
@   IN A    123.456.78.910
www IN A    123.456.78.910
www CNAME   @
ww  CNAME   @
dev IN A    123.456.78.910
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have CNAME *and* any other record for the same DNS name:

```
www IN A    123.456.78.910
www CNAME   @
```

In this case the second line is superfluous, you can delete the CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the IN in CNAME and the www CNAME is redundant. It should be:

```
@   IN A    123.456.78.910
www IN A    123.456.78.910
ww  IN CNAME   @
dev IN A    123.456.78.910
```

If it were up to me though, I would change it to:

```
@   IN A       123.456.78.910
www IN A       123.456.78.910
ww  IN A       123.456.78.910
dev IN A       123.456.78.910
```

Use A records where possible, saves having to create MX and NS records. It also saves having to fetch any CNAME/A records it is attached to.